# Set nginx proxy for react multi-stage build with docker compose

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, nginx

I am - once again - very confused, with nginx, docker and react.

Here is what is what I want: 1.) a Django REST api that exposes a port only locally 2.) I want the staticfiles of the REST api handled by nginx 3.) a ReactJS front end that is served via nginx on port 80 (I dont know if it is nessesary to serve react via nginx - but I've heard it reduces image size).

**The problem:** It does not work. All containers can run individually but serving them via docker compose will not run properly. I dont seem to be able to proxy to the api and frontend.

**I hint to my problem:** What I am seeing is that the image I am layering in reactJS "tiangolo/node-frontend:10" also copies a nginx.conf file that may overwrite mine.

Using a million tutorials, I am here:

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream website_rest {
        server restapi:8000;
    }

upstream website_frontend {
    server frontend:8080;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location /rest_call/ {
        proxy_pass http://website_rest;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /rest_call/staticfiles/ {
        alias /usr/src/website-dj/staticfiles/;
    }

}
```

**This is the dockerfile for react:**

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /website-rj
COPY package*.json /website-rj/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /website-rj/
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /website-rj/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Dockercompose:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    expose:
      - 8080
    build: "./website_rj_docker"
    volumes:
      - ./website_rj_docker/build:/usr/src/website-rj/
  restapi:
    build: "./website_dj_docker/"
    # command: python /usr/src/website-dj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=rest.settings.production
    command: gunicorn rest.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./website_dj_docker/:/usr/src/website-dj/
      - static_volume:/usr/src/website-dj/staticfiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY='something...'
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=postgres
      - SQL_USER=something...
      - SQL_PASSWORD=something...
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/website-dj/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - restapi
```

Comment: The problem: the volumes defined in your docker compose file are not available during docker build but only on docker (compose) run. 
The only solution I see is to have a node-container building your react app as the run-CMD, using your docker volume, which will then be accessible from your nginx container - also on docker (compose) run only.

Comment: Open issue related to mounting docker volumes during docker build: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14080

Comment: Good example showing how to combine Docker, react,a backend service and nginx: https://github.com/ifischer/django-nginx-reactjs-docker